# Dependency Injection best practice when new object graph is needed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm new to dependency injection and still trying to wrap my head around it. As I understand, best practice according to the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://manning.com/seemann) states that the object graph is created once at app startup in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and the container is not accessed again in the application.

What happens when the user hits the new/open button?

Normally I would create new instances of the object graph portion needed (`Forest`) but if I'm not supposed to access the container, do I call a clear method that propagates the object graph? Do I somehow use lifetime management and make sure there are no current references to the portion of the object graph needed to be new?

Edit:

Example using MVVM/WPF

```
public class Bootstrapper {
    public void Initialize() {
        Container.Register<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
        Container.Register<IForest, Forest>();
        Container.Register<ITrees, Trees>();
        Container.Register<ITree, Tree>();
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : IMainViewModel {
    private IForest _forest;

    public MainViewModel(IForest forest) { _forest = forest; }

    public void New() { Forest.Clear(); }
    public void AddTrees(){ _trees.Add(new Tree()); }
}

public class ViewModel : IViewModel {
    private ITrees _trees;
    private ITree _selectedTree;

    public ViewModel(ITrees trees){ _trees = trees; }

    public void AddTrees() { _trees.Add(new Tree()); }
}

public class Forest : IForest {
    private ITrees _trees;

    public Forest(ITrees trees){ _trees = trees; }

    public void AddTree(ITree tree){ _trees.Add(tree); }
    public void Clear(){ _trees.Clear(); }
}

public class Trees : ITrees {
    public List<ITree> trees = new List<ITree>();

    public void Add(ITree tree){ trees.Add(tree); }
    public void Clear(){ trees.Clear(); }
}
```

Comment: "according to Dependency Injection .NET". Are you refering to the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://manning.com/seemann/) by Mark Seemann?

Comment: "What happens when the user hits the new/open button?". Please state the technology? Are you targeting a client application like Win Forms, WPF or UWP, or a web application like ASP.NET MVC or something else?

Comment: Yes, by Mark Seemann.  I'm using WPF/MVVM.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Without that, recommending any tool is a fool’s errand.

Comment: theMayer:  why a container?  We have a team of 6 devs rewriting our code base that has a large object graph that is quite unwieldy to setup and maintain using poor man's DI.  Also, given that our project is still in its early stage and constructors can change frequently, the container appears to reduce the amount of changes needed to be made in the factory if using poor man's DI for setup and the unit tests change a lot less as the constructors change.  It also makes mocking easier for unit testing as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> according to the book Dependency Injection in .NET states that the object graph is created once at app startup in the Composition Root and the container is accessed again in the application.

Nowhere does the book state that an application's object graph should be created just once, and it certainly does not state that the container should be accessed from the application.

The 1st edition of the book however states the following (not exact quotes):

- Objects graphs should be composed as close as possible to the application's entry point (section 3.3.1, page 75)
- Object graphs are *configured* once (at application startup), but created (resolved) many time throughout the application's lifetime (section 3.3.2, page 84)
- Asking a DI Container for granular services from anywhere else but the Composition Root implies the Service Locator anti-pattern. (section 5.4, page 155)

To summarize:

- Object graphs are *always* composed inside the Composition Root
- They are configured/registered just once, during application startup
- Any time a new object graph is required, it can be composed. This means that object graphs can be composed many times during the application's lifetime
- The code that requests a new object graph should *always* be part of the Composition Root to prevent the Service Locator anti-pattern.

> but if I'm not supposed to access the container, do I call a clear method that propagates the object graph?

The answer to this seeming paradox is: **Abstraction!**

To be able to construct an object graph lazily from within an already-constructed component, you can define a specific Abstraction (an Abstract Factory to be more precise) that allows the creation of that specific service. This Factory abstraction can be *defined* on application level, and *implemented* inside the Composition Root.

For instance:

```
// Defined in application
public interface IForestFactory
{
    IForest Create();
}

// Defined inside the Composition Root
public class ForestFactory : IForestFactory
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public ForestFactory(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IForest Create() {
        return this.container.GetInstance<IForest>();
    }
}

// Inside the Bootstrapper
var factory = new ForestFactory(Container);
Container.Register<IForestFactory>(() => factory);
```

The [second edition of the book](https://manning.com/seemann2) however describes that these kinds of factories are often a code smell. Instead of using a factory, it is typically better to use a [Virtual Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

A Virtual Proxy is a stand-in for an object that should be created lazily. A Virtual Proxy however implements the same Abstraction as the lazily created object. This allows the Virtual Proxy to be injected into a consumer, without the consumer having to know of the existence of the Virtual Proxy.

In your case that means that you create a Virtual Proxy for `IForest`, for instance:

```
// Defined inside the Composition Root
public class LazyForestProxy : IForest
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public LazyForestProxy(Container container){
        this.container = container;
    }

    // Implement IForest members
    void IForest.Run() {
        var forest = GetInstance();

        // Forward the call to the 'real' forest
        forest.Run();
    }        

    private IForest GetInstance() {
        return this.container.GetInstance<IForest>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.  Just one question though.  If we register the object graph once at startup, what if we have an object in the graph that is loaded from file?  When it is resolved it needs this object to do the injections properly.  Is this an exception to the rule or is there another way to handle it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What does it mean to "have an object in the graph that is loaded from file"? Are you talking about late binding (see page 17 of the 1st edition)?